# Rails adjust setting two child models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model

I have a model `Orders` with two children `Items` and `fulfillments`.

When a `fulfillment` is created I need to set `Items.fulfillment_complete` to true.

Is setting this in the controller the best way to do it?

`current_order.fulfillment.save
current_order.items(fulfillment_complete: true)`

Or is there a better way to do this to ensure that one is following MVC practices.

Comment: Model names would normally be singular. Do you have one Fullfillment for each Item in the order (I assume an "item" is somthing like product+quantity+customisations, not a product itself?) or is it one Fullfillment for the entire order?  Either way why not just use the presence of the relation itself?

Comment: You are basically trying to do `caching`, by storing data (`bool` in this case) to reflect the existence/state of another data. For something as simple as that, I suggest you to not cache this information and just compute it (method `Item#fulfilled?` would return the result of `self.fulfillments.exists?`) -- The problem with caching, is not to create the data to do the caching, it is to make sure you invalid this cache whenever it is needed.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about models `Item` & `Fulfillment` ? Then it will be much easier to understand what you want and how to implement right solution.

Answer (score 0):

If `Fulfillment` and `Item` are both children of `Order` then your `items` can delegate to the parent `Order` when inquiring whether they've been fulfilled.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order

  scope :fulfilled, -> { includes(order: :fulfillment).where.not(fulfillments: { order_id: nil })

  def fulfilled?
    order.fullfillment.present?
  end
end
```

This ensures you only have a single source of truth regarding fulfillment status.